# Decompress HTTP response using Python socket

Tags: python, http, sockets, compression, gzip

I'm using `socket` with python 2.7.12 and whenever I read the body of a HTTP response like the following:

```
response_body = server_socket.recv(body_len)
```

I receive compressed data (compressed with gzip).
After a lot of not working solutions from Google, I would like to as if there is any way to read the HTTP requests / responses as a plain text using python socket?

Comment: Parse the HTTP headers manually and then extract the request body and use the [`gzip` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) to decompress it. Good luck with that though, that's gonna be annoying... you are far better off just using `urllib` or any other HTTP library

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MarcoBonelli, for using `urllib` do I need to write a new python server without using `socket`, or perhaps `urllib` can be used on top of `socket` based server? (I'm trying to write a HTTP proxy server)

Comment: What you are writing is not just a server, in the sense that your proxy will have to act as a client and make requests to the actual server. That is what I was talking about. For the server part you can use whatever you want really. Those are two different components, you can implement one with `urllib` or whatever HTTP lib and the other one with sockets if you want.

Comment: I don't think you can use `urllib` on top of `socket` in order to make a server. There isn't much in the standard Python library that helps, maybe [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) from the `http` module and `socketserver`, but that's a very rudimental server tbh.